# Obtener tipo de atributo usando keyof en typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

Estoy creando 2 interfaces en typescript:

Interface 1:

```
interface Interface1 {
    key1: string
    key2: number
}
```

Interface 2:

```
interface Interface2 {
    key: keyof Interface1
    fun(value: Interface1[this["key"]]): void
}
```

Pero al momento de usar la Interface 2 el parámetro de `fun` siempre me da `any` ¿qué hago para que me de el tipo según el valor de `key`?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de TS utilizas? He hecho lo mismo en el [playground](https://tsplay.dev/w62zyw) y el resultado es el esperado: `(method) Interface2.fun(value: string | number): void`. Lo único *raro* que veo es que si utilizas `fun: () => {}` es completamente válido. Tendré que indagar más al respecto, pues noté que pasa con cualquier *signature* que utilices.

Comment: Ok, después de una rápida investigación encontré en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28252843/7927192) en el homónimo en ingles que es un compartamiento completamente normal. En pocas palabras lo que se valida como tal, es el tipo en el retorno y no los parámetros que se pasan a la función.

Comment: Si, pero me gustaría que, en caso de poner `key: "key1"` me de en el parametro solo `string`

Comment: Creo que eso es imposible, al menos por el momento debido a las razones explicadas en las respuestas de la pregunta que te recomendé.